# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried to do a bot and it worked pretty well but now there is this error in my "deploy-commands" file, yet I don't think I touched anything in this file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({version: '9'}).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands});
        console.log('Les command ont étés enregistrées !')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

What's this error please and how I can solve it ?

My ping.js :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { CommandInteraction } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Renvoie le nombre de ping'),
        /**
         * 
         * @param {CommandInteraction} Interaction 
         */
    async execute (Interaction) {
        await Interaction.reply('Pong');
    
        const message = await Interaction.fetchReply();

        return Interaction.editReply(`Le message a mis ${message.createdTimestamp - Interaction.createdTimestamp} ms.\nTon ping est de ${Interaction.client.ws.ping} ms.`);
    }
}
```

Comment: what line throws the error?

Comment: line 11 ( commands.push(command.data.toJSON()); )

Comment: Can we see an example of a command file

Comment: I have add a command file

Answer (score -3):

You shall declare command outside the for loop

```js
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
```

Comment: How will they be able to traverse all their command files if it's outside the loop? Where would `file` come from?